# When I start the PowerShell script from the CMD this is not setting the variables well

Tags: powershell, batch-file

If I start the command from PowerShell it works perfectly instead of CMD this happens:
[Imgur Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W35KU.png)

```
PowerShell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "$MangaPage=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri %MangaLink%; $MangaName=$MangaPage.ParsedHtml.querySelector('#top-in > div.top-title > span.hideM0 > a').innerText; Write-Host $MangaName; $ChapterNumber=$MangaPage.ParsedHtml.querySelector('#combobox > option.selected').innerText; Write-Host $ChapterNumber; $PageNumber=$MangaPage.ParsedHtml.querySelector('#pageSelect > option.selected').innerText; Write-Host $PageNumber; $URLImage=$MangaPage.ParsedHtml.querySelector('#mainImg').src.replace('about:', 'https:'); Write-Host $URLImage; $FileExtension=$URLImage.SubString($URLImage.lastIndexOf('.')+1); Write-Host $FileExtension; $FileName='$.ChapterNumber'+'_'+'$PageNumber'+'_'+'$MangaName'+'.'+'$FileExtension'; $Folder=('$MangaName\$ChapterNumber'); If(!(Test-Path $Folder)) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Folder }; Invoke-WebRequest $URLImage -OutFile $Folder\$FileName"
```

Comment: please don't edit the question to say that it was solved. If you found the answer yourself, post a new answer below and click on the green checkmark. For more information spend a minute for a quick [tour] to understand how this community works

Answer (score 0):

> ***[About PowerShell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe?view=powershell-5.1)***
>
> When the value of Command is a string, Command must be the last
>   parameter specified because any characters typed after the command are
>   interpreted as the command arguments.
>
> The Command parameter only accepts a script block for execution when
>   it can recognize the value passed to Command as a ScriptBlock type.
>   This is only possible when running PowerShell.exe from another
>   PowerShell host. The ScriptBlock type may be contained in an existing
>   variable, returned from an expression, or parsed by the PowerShell
>   host as a literal script block enclosed in curly braces {}, before
>   being passed to PowerShell.exe.
>
> ***In cmd.exe, there is no such thing as a script block (or ScriptBlock***
>   ***type), so the value passed to Command will always be a string.*** You can
>   write a script block inside the string, but instead of being executed
>   it will behave exactly as though you typed it at a typical PowerShell
>   prompt, printing the contents of the script block back out to you.
>
> A string passed to Command will still be executed as PowerShell, so
>   the script block curly braces are often not required in the first
>   place when running from cmd.exe. ***To execute an inline script block***
>   ***defined inside a string, the call operator & can be used:***
>
> console
>
> "& {}"

```
PowerShell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command  "&{ $MangaPage=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri %MangaLink%; $MangaName=$MangaPage.ParsedHtml.querySelector('#top-in > div.top-title > span.hideM0 > a').innerText; Write-Host $MangaName; $ChapterNumber=$MangaPage.ParsedHtml.querySelector('#combobox > option.selected').innerText; Write-Host $ChapterNumber; $PageNumber=$MangaPage.ParsedHtml.querySelector('#pageSelect > option.selected').innerText; Write-Host $PageNumber; $URLImage=$MangaPage.ParsedHtml.querySelector('#mainImg').src.replace('about:', 'https:'); Write-Host $URLImage; $FileExtension=$URLImage.SubString($URLImage.lastIndexOf('.')+1); Write-Host $FileExtension; $FileName='$.ChapterNumber'+'_'+'$PageNumber'+'_'+'$MangaName'+'.'+'$FileExtension'; $Folder=('$MangaName\$ChapterNumber'); If(!(Test-Path $Folder)) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Folder }; Invoke-WebRequest $URLImage -OutFile $Folder\$FileName}"
```

Comment: I solved... but not with "& {}" i replaced all the ' with /"" idk why but now it's working...

Comment: Glad to see you hit on a resolution. However, going forward, know that PowerShell has a bunch of special characters and in given use cases, can be leveraged, but using the right tone depends on what you are trying to do. Documents here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7 --- and 'How-to: Escape characters, Delimiters and Quotes' https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html